# Vulnerability of symlink overwriting

Tags: linux, security, symlink

On my distro, `/sbin` is symlinked to `/usr/sbin`. What is stopping a malicious program from overwriting that link to point to somewhere else and waiting for a superuser to execute something to obtain higher privileges?

From what I understand, symlinks cannot have their permissions modified from `777`; just redirecting the link would be trivial. However, I haven't been able to find any mention of this problem online as a problem to be weary of, so there must be some mechanism preventing an attack like this.

Comment: probably a duplicate - you can't modify the link if you lack permission to recreate it, since symbolic links can only ***be*** modified by re-creating them.

Comment: Permission for parent directory is stopping. Overwritting a symlink (or whatever else) requires write permission to it's parent directory.

Comment: The root directory, /, is root:root 755 thus a non-root user cannot overwrite files/symlinks in it  There's no vulnerability.